# Phing: gitclone incredibly slow

Tags: php, git, github, phing

A part of my build.xml config is

```
<gitclone repository="${repo}" targetPath="${directory}" />
```

The repository I am cloning is not big, around 30M and 10k of objects.
If I do `git clone` in console, cloning takes around 30 seconds, which is OK. But if I try to execute phing config, it can take up to 30 minutes. Interesting, is that files appear in the directory in about same 30 seconds, but nothing happens, phing build script is not executed further.

Also, there's no difference in  running `<gitclone />` or `<exec command="git clone ${repo} ${directory}" />`, they both take too much time.

I am using latest Phing version on Ubuntu and github private repo, which means I need to enter username and password every time I clone. But if I do git clone in console first, and then (while my credentials are still remembered), Phing works just fine.

Could it be a bug, or something else?

Comment: So Phing doesn't ask for a password?  Sounds like it's waiting for you to enter a password but not giving you a way to do so.  Can you set up credentials via SSH keys with github so a password isn't necessary?

Comment: Phing asks for a PW and after I enter it, Phing does clone, but after clone is done (I can see it by the cloned files), nothing happens for half an hour.